# Error : "TypeError:expressJwt not a function"

Tags: express-jwt

i faced with problem while try set the authenticate using express to my app.
and this is my code:

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt'); 

function authJwt(){
    secret = process.env.secret;
    return expressJwt({
      secret,
      algorithms: ["HS256"],    
    });
}
module.exports = authJwt;
```

Comment: Which version of express-jwt are you using? The question about this error comes up frequently, but there are different answers, also depending on the version.

Comment: i solve it by try to import like this: 
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');